# Positional argument error when using 'when' in pyspark

Tags: python, database, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df_categories4 = df_categories3.select("alias", "title", 
f.when(df_categories.parents == 0).otherwise(df_categories3.parents[0])).show()
```

It shows an error of when() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'. But if i place a value after the '0', it says that there is an error that can't be resolve.

How would I approach this problem?

Thanks.

**Original Error:**

```
TypeError: when() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

**Error After Entering Value after 0:**

```
AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '(`parents` = 0)' due to data type mismatch: 
differing types in '(`parents` = 0)' (array<string> and int).;;\n'Project 
[alias#226, title#230, CASE WHEN (parents#229 = 0) THEN 1 ELSE parents#229[0] 
END AS CASE WHEN (parents = 0) THEN 1 ELSE parents[0] END#1079]\n+- 
AnalysisBarrier\n      +- Filter ((array_contains(country_whitelist#228, US) || 
array_contains(country_whitelist#228, CA)) || isnull(country_whitelist#228))\n         
+- Filter (NOT (array_contains(country_blacklist#227, US) && 
array_contains(country_blacklist#227, CA)) || isnull(country_blacklist#227))\n            
+-
```

Relation[alias#226,country_blacklist#227,country_whitelist#228,parents#229,title#230] json\n"

Comment: What is the actual error, when you place a value after the 0?

Comment: What do you mean add the 0? Like add another value after the 0?

Comment: It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing it.

Comment: I just attached the photo of the error message after adding a value after the 0

Comment: While the original error is 
   TypeError: when() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

Comment: Please include code and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external links.

Comment: when requires a value that should be used if the condition is fulfilled, if I remember correctly. e.g. `when(df_categories.parents == 0, SOME_VALUE).otherwise(...)`

Comment: There i just edited the question

Comment: @gaw yep that's what I thought but after entering a value it still displays an error

Comment: "parents" is array, and compare array with zero is wrong. Maybe, lenght have to be compared with zero.

Comment: if you want to check if the value is set (e.g. if Null), you should use `df_categories.parents.isNull()`. So make sure that the types for the comparison match. That was the solution to the error, when I run your code with another dataframe

Comment: @gaw im not checking if it's null though. '0' is an actual value on the dataset. Would it still be the same process? Can you provide an example with 0?

Comment: I think it strongly depends on the dataframe schema and the structure of your data. But I will post an example.

Comment: The structure of parents column worked fine for all of the other codes. So im not sure what the error is

Answer (score 0):

I think your error might be depending on the structure of you `parents` column.

When I run the following code, it works out fine:

```py
test_df = spark.createDataFrame([("a","b",1),("c","d",0)], ("alias","value","number"))
test_df.select("alias","value",when(test_df.number==0,"0").otherwise(test_df.number)).show()
```

Results:

```
+-----+-----+---------------------------------------------+ 
|alias|value|CASE WHEN (number = 0) THEN 0 ELSE number END|    
+-----+-----+---------------------------------------------+
|  a  |  b  |   1                                         | 
|  c  |  d  |   0                                         | 
+-----+-----+---------------------------------------------+
```

Note: I removed the `[0]` from the number since you can only directly access an element here if it is an array, but then the test with `== 0` would not make sense. So I think you have an error here, because you test `parents==0`, which indicates parents is a numerical value and later you access `parents[0]`, which does not work for numerical values. So you get a "mismatched type error"

If you want to deal with Arrays in the corresponding column you should use something like:

```
test_df = spark.createDataFrame([("a","b",[1,]),("c","d",[0,])], ("alias","value","number"))
test_df.select("alias","value",when(array_contains(test_df.number,0),"0").otherwise(test_df.number)).show()
```

Comment: If parents is indeed an array, and you can access the element at index `0`, you have to modify your comparison to something like: `df_categories.parents[0] == 0` or `array_contains(df_categories.parents, 0)` depending on the position of the element you want to check or if you just want to know whether the value is in the array

Comment: I still do not understand. My parents structure remains untouched and it has worked perfectly for other queries. The error is mentioning data type mismatches so I am assuming the strings and number values may be the issue?

Comment: also i saw for your comparison you use `df_categories.parents` and later you use `df_categories3.parents`  is this intended?

Comment: It also tells you in the error message: that the comparison does not work, because you want to compare `(array<string> and int)`  which is not possible

Comment: df_categories was a previous dataframe that used the select method previously. df_categories3 is a new dataframe so it is intended.

Comment: So basically I should have it where df_categories.parents == "0"?

Comment: yes. There you try to compare an array with a single number or a single string

Comment: Nevermind, I just tried that method and it still provides the same error.

Comment: No I mean you have an array of strings as your parents column. And you can not compare this to 0 or "0". So you have to use `array_contains(df_categories.parents, 0)` if you want to check for a `0` inside the array for example

Comment: So would I put that array statement inside my f.when()?

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding what you're saying at all

Comment: your when should look like:  `f.when(array_contains(df_categories.parents, "0"), SOME_VALUE).otherwise(..)` and replace SOME_VALUE with the value you want to have if the comparison is fulfilled

Comment: This is what I have: import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df_categories4 = df_categories3.select("alias", "title", f.when(df_categories.parents, "0"), 0).otherwise(df_categories3.parents[0]).show()

Comment: In addition it still provides an error with: Invalid argument, not a string or column: 0 of type <class 'int'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.

Comment: this means the value you did in the when has to be defined differently:
`df_categories4 = df_categories3.select("alias", "title", f.when(array_contains(df_categories.parents, "0"), 0).otherwise(df_categories3.parents[0]).show()`
You forgot the `array_contains` which could be the error, but if it still remains try to encapsulate the `0` in lit --> `lit(0)`